# divide the string with RegExp in Groovy

Tags: regex, string, groovy, split

well, i put xml-response with a lot of symbols, like this:

```
def xmlString = "<TAG1>1239071ABCDEFGH</TAG1><TAG2>1239071ABCDEFGH</TAG2>"
```

using xmlSlurper to leave only digits

```
def node = 
new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlString)
    def nodelist = [node.tag1.tag2]
```

after this "node" got a value like "1239071123907112390711239071" 
and i try to put java RegExp to separate the digits by 7

```
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString( nodelist.node.split("(?<=\G.{7})") ))
```

Where i did wrong? it doesn't work

Comment: How does `<TAG1>1239071ABCDEFGH</TAG1><TAG2>1239071ABCDEFGH</TAG2>` give you `1239071123907112390711239071`?  Then why are you splitting by 7 chars?

Comment: Also, XmlSlurper won't slurp that Xml as it's not valid (no root node)

Comment: Also, I believe `def nodelist = [node.tag1.tag2]` would return `[ null ]`

Comment: there's a lot of `<TAG1><TAG2>...<TAGX>` tags with same type of content, but i need only digits and separate it by 7 chars to get [1239071 1239071 1239071] etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have some valid xml like:

```
def xmlString = """<document>
                  |    <TAG1>1239071ABCDEFGH</TAG1>
                  |    <TAG2>1239071ABCDEFGH</TAG2>
                  |</document>""".stripMargin()
```

Then you can get all elements starting with `TAG`, and for each of these trim off the end chars which aren't digits:

```
def nodeList = new XmlSlurper().parseText( xmlString )
                               .'**'
                               .findAll { node ->
                                   node.name().startsWith( 'TAG' )
                               }
                               .collect { node ->
                                   it.text().takeWhile { ch ->
                                       Character.isDigit( ch )
                                   }
                               }
```

`nodeList` in this example would then equal:

```
assert nodeList == ['1239071', '1239071']
```

If you want to keep these numbers associated with the `TAG` that contained them (assuking `TAGn` tags are unique), then you can change to `collectEntries`

```
def nodeList = new XmlSlurper().parseText( xmlString )
                               .'**'
                               .findAll { node ->
                                   node.name().startsWith( 'TAG' )
                               }    
                               .collectEntries { node ->
                                   [ node.name(), node.text().takeWhile { Character.isDigit( it ) } ]
                               }


assert nodeList == [TAG1:'1239071', TAG2:'1239071']
```

Comment: thank you! that's very good help! and one more please: what to do if not only `TAGn` unique, but values too: '1239071', '1239082', etc

Comment: The Map variant should be fine, values in a map can be unique or duplicated it doesn't matter